# Display text in columns with Python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to display this:

```
Huawei Internet Key :    10.0     80   800.0
Wimax USB Stick :        50.0     25   1250.0
```

instead of :

```
Huawei Internet Key :    10.0     80   800.0
Wimax USB Stick :    50.0     25   1250.0
```

Please, how do I proceed with python 2.7? (Sorry for my english)